# How can I get 4k @ 60Hz at 4:2:0 working in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: nvidia, 4k-monitor

Got another question,

I've been working on this for a few days now, and I cannot get it to work at all.  :(

I know it works in Windows, but Linux is hanging me up.

Here are my specs:
  nvidia GTX970,
  Vizio M43-C1 4k TV

And if it matters:
  Asus Z170a
  Intel i5 Skylake

What I've tried:

-Setting it through nvidia panel
(Have 2 entries for 60Hz, one reports failed to set metamode and the other gives a black screen with no signal)

-Setting it through xrandr

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 3840x2160 -r 59.94 --verbose (and)
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 3840x2160 -r 60 --verbose
```

This reports at fail:

```
screen 0: 3840x2160 945x532 mm 103.13dpi
crtc 0:    3840x2160  59.94 +0+0 "HDMI-0"
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
crtc 0: disable
crtc 1: disable
crtc 2: disable
crtc 3: disable
screen 0: revert
crtc 0: revert
crtc 1: revert
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  54
  Current serial number in output stream:  54
```

-Updated the drivers to latest beta (370.xx)

Any insight would be appreciated, thank you.  For now I'm off to work!

Edit:
Some research here, I hope it can be helpful.

1. Threads from nvidia linux dev forums:
   https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/939971/linux/4k-60hz-works-in-windows-not-in-linux-bounty-offered-for-fix-/1
   ***Edit 3: Workaround may have been found for me in this thread.*

   https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/950134/linux/4k-on-hdmi-2-0/
   *This guy says resolved but I really cannot gather what he even did.*

   https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/818079/linux/980gtx-no-support-for-4k-60hz-4-2-0-only-30hz-/post/4496595/#4496595
   *And apparently **this** guy got it working with 349.12 drivers from over a year ago?  What?  This one was a real gut punch.*
2. Some info from my system that makes me want to pull my hair out:
   From **/var/log/Xorg.0.log**:

   > [  8026.035] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): VIZ M43-C1 (DFP-1): connected
   >   [  8026.035] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): VIZ M43-C1 (DFP-1): Internal TMDS
   >   [  8026.035] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): VIZ M43-C1 (DFP-1): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock

   So 600MHz max?  Okay...

   ```
   xrandr --verbose


   3840x2160 (0x1c6) 593.410MHz +HSync +VSync
   h: width  3840 start 4016 end 4104 total 4400 skew    0 clock 134.87KHz
   v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  59.94Hz
   ```

   I may be missing something fundamental here, I'm not sure.  Seems to check out to me (600MHz vs 593.410MHz,) am I wrong?
3. As per my TV's specs, HDMI port 5 can support up to 1080p at 120Hz and 4k at 60Hz.

   ```
   xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 -r 119.88
   ```

   <del>This works fine, and I achieve 120Hz on 1080p.</del>
   120Hz on 1080p results in horizontal lines flashing across the screen intermittently.

For now I think it's time for bed.

Edit 2:
Still no luck here, but some new luck came my way-  My EVGA step-up to 1070 finally started.  Will report back on changes (if any) after installing.

Edit 3:
It would appear that I may be incredibly lucky.  While others with a similar issue have been waiting for months, I have the timing to step in and only wait a few weeks.  I'll have to wait for my new card to come in to test it, but it looks promising.  nVidia has acknowledged it as a bug in the drivers and provided a EDID from another TV in the meantime to override with that appears to make 60Hz on 4k work at the cost of losing 120Hz on 1080p.  I can't wait to test this!

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/146841/why-does-text-look-so-horrible-on-my-hd-monitor/223920#223920 .  You need to adjust monitor settings as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any of you facing a similar issue, a workaround has been found until nvidia releases their next driver and it works its way into repos.
**With this workaround, you will lose the option to display 1080p at 120Hz.**

First, please see:
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/939971/linux/4k-60hz-works-in-windows-not-in-linux-workaround-found-/post/4959257/#4959257

Download the edid from that post.  Note where you store it.

## Note:  It is possible to break your display manager if this is done incorrectly, or if your monitor isn't the same as mine.  Be ready to start in recovery to remove this next file we create to reverse the issue.

If you are on 16.04 like myself, there is no xorg.conf file and if you make one, it has a mind to vanish with every system update.  Instead, navigate to:

```
cd /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

Next, create a new file here.  It's important that you use superuser permissions.  Personally, I just sudo gedit, others tell me I'm bad for it.

```
sudo gedit 50-nvidia.conf
```

Paste the following into it:
*If you do not have a Vizio M43-C1, please create your own xorg settings through the nvidia control panel and add the last Option to yours.  You only need the Monitor section.  I will bold what you need to add.*

```
#Not First Line
Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "VIZ M43-C1"
    HorizSync       15.0 - 140.0
    VertRefresh     25.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
    Option         "CustomEDID" "HDMI-0:/path/to/edid.txt"
EndSection
#Not Last Line
```

**Option         "CustomEDID" "HDMI-0:/path/to/edid.txt"**
*This is the workaround.*

**Note that HDMI-0 needs to be replaced with your current display.**
To find yours, run:

```
xrandr
```

From the output, find the one that says connected.  For example,

```
HDMI-0 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
```

Shows my display is HDMI-0, so this is what I use in my 50-nvidia.conf.

After you're done, simply reboot.  If all done correctly, you should be able to login normally and set 4k @60Hz 4:2:0 with no problem.

Again, this is just a workaround.  Hopefully no one will ever need to do this in a few months when the new driver is released.

Comment: Is this still happening? The reason I ask is because am about to buy a 4k soon (Samsung model) and I have an nvidia 1080 gtx.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado I added an answer below how I got my 4k 60fps working on Samsung. Long story short, I had to explicitly enable "Input Signal Plus" on Samsung to get it report correct supported modes to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 9):

I was having a similar problem with an LG 4k TV, but it turns out that I had to enable the option "HDMI ULTRA HD Deep Colour" on the tv to make it work.

Comment: On LG monitors you can enable it in Menu -> Picture -> Picture Adjust ->  HDMI ULTRA HD Deep Color

Comment: I had the same problem on my 4k TV, I had to enable the HDMI 2.0 standard on my monitor.

Answer (score 1):

I had to manually **enable UHD ("Input Signal Plus") on my TV** to get 4k 60 fps working on my Samsung TV (QE43Q60RAT). This can be done through `General -> External Device Manager -> Input Signal Plus -> [x] HDMI 1`. The Samsung e-Manual wasn't half bad, it guided me to "Input Signal Plus" when I searched the manual for UHD.

The funny thing is that, it used to be called UHD in the input expert settings in previous Samsung version, but maybe "experience" wasn't what they were looking for and now UHD is buried under "Input Signal Plus".

LG seems to call it **"HDMI ULTRA HD Deep Colour"**.

Some manufacturers call it **"HDMI 2.0"**.

After enabling the UHD, I was immediately able to switch to 4k 60 fps in the Ubuntu 20.04 Settings menu for Display.

**Some technical details:**

EDID before "Input Signal Plus" **(Note the 300 MHz pixel clock)**

```
sudo get-edid -b 7 | parse-edid
7
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
Only trying 7 as per your request.
256-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 7
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "SAMSUNG"
    ModelName "SAMSUNG"
    VendorName "SAM"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 1 of 2019
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 950 540
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "false"
    Horizsync 15-81
    VertRefresh 24-75
    # Maximum pixel clock is 300MHz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1152x864, 75Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x720, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x800, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1440x900, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1600x900, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1680x1050, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1920x1080, 60Hz

    #Extension block found. Parsing...
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 95)
#DOUBLE WARNING: It's your first mode, too, so this may actually be important.
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 93)
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 94)
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 98)
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 100)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

EDID after "Input Signal Plus" **(Note the 600 MHz pixel clock)**:

```
sudo get-edid -b 7 | parse-edid
7
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
Only trying 7 as per your request.
256-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 7
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "SAMSUNG"
    ModelName "SAMSUNG"
    VendorName "SAM"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 1 of 2019
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 950 540
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "false"
    Horizsync 15-135
    VertRefresh 24-75
    # Maximum pixel clock is 600MHz
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you @jaako. What model is this?

Comment: I added the model (QE43Q60RAT) to above.