# Getting 4k on GT730 and Samsung U28D590 over miniHDMI

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution

Trying to get this to work, but can't go over 1920x1080. I've tried this fix, and it did nothing:

[How can I get 4k @ 60Hz at 4:2:0 working in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815075/how-can-i-get-4k-60hz-at-420-working-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Currently running 381.22, but previously a 375.xx driver. Same results with both.

Any other suggestions? Do all GT730 cards support 4k? Is it the cable perhaps?